# Restricting BING Map searches to a country in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

The question title pretty much sums it up. I want to restrict the map search to USA only. Right now I'm only using the [BING Maps geocode service](http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc?wsdl), so I guess there should be a way in there to do this. For example, if I search Paris, I only want to get 'Paris, TX' and not 'Paris, France'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just appending `", USA"` to the query?

Without knowing how you're capturing/sourcing the values you're searching for it's hard to offer a more specific solution.

Comment: @Carlo what do yoou mean "safe"?

Comment: Not sure, any query that could break this.

Comment: Yoou're just doing a free text search so it will depend on how whatever is input will be interpreted by the geocode service. If you're allowing the user to enter the location then they could enter gibberish anyway so you must already have a way of allowing them to refine or change their search if necessary.

Comment: This might work in scenarios where we need to restrict to a single country. Not sure if query supports `OR` so that multiple countries can be included. Like appending `Australia, NZ` not sure if this would search for locations common to these or include both.